# Oracle SELECT query to find the smallest distinct delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table

```
C1      |  Path
--------|-----------
T1      | T0/T1
T2      | T0/T1/T2
T3      | T0/T1/T2/T3
X1      | T0/X0/X1
T2      | T0/X0/X1/T2
T3      | T0/X0/X1/T2/T3
T3      | T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3
Y3      | T0/X0/X2/Y3
Y4      | T0/X0/X2/Y3/Y4
```

I need to write q query or code which should return smallest distinct delimited string as shown below

```
C1      |  Path
--------|-----------
T1      | T0/T1
X1      | T0/X0/X1
T3      | T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3
Y3      | T0/X0/X2/Y3
```

Ex: `T0/T1` is a substring of `T0/T1/T2` and `T0/T1/T2/T3`. 
`T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3` is not substring of any other string. It is distinct. 

Can you please help me to write this query in oracle

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: what does "smallest distinct delimited string" mean?

Comment: I thought of writing a code, which loops through each Path (ex: T0/T1) and marks those path (To/T1/T2, T0/T1/T2/T3) which has the given path in it. The ones which are not marked at the end of the loop are the paths that are needed as output

Comment: Could you explain a logic ? Why `T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3` is the smalest when it looks like the longest ?

Comment: Ex: T0/T1 is a substring of T0/T1/T2 and T0/T1/T2/T3.  T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3 is not substring of any other string. It is distinct.

Comment: you should explain it further in the post and not here in the comment. and please post the codes that you have tried so far so that we can help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
ON t1.Path <> t2.Path
   AND t1.path LIKE '%'||t2.Path||'%' 
WHERE t2.c1 IS NULL
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3f87/3

```
| C1 |           PATH |
|----|----------------|
| T1 |          T0/T1 |
| X1 |       T0/X0/X1 |
| T3 | T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3 |
| Y3 |    T0/X0/X2/Y3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This query works  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf32e/19

```
With X as
(select 'T0/T1' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/T1/T2' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/T1/T2/T3' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/X0/X1' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/X0/X1/T2' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/X0/X1/T2/T3' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/Y0/Y1/Y2/T3' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/X0/X2/Y3' c1 from dual
union
select 'T0/X0/X2/Y3/Y4' c1 from dual),
Y as (
select distinct X1.C1 YC1 from X X1, X X2
where X1.C1 like '%'||X2.C1||'%' and X1.C1<>X2.C1)
select * from X where not exists
(select 1 from Y where YC1=X.C1)
```